# CSS underline issue with typeface on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, underline, typeface

I'm not sure if this is a typeface bug, but typeface renders double underline on anchor text that has *text-decoration: underline* style on chrome. Any thoughts please?

By the way, I'm using typeface 0.15.

Thanks.

Edit:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="typeface-0.15.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="myriad_pro_regular.typeface.js"></script> 
<style type="text/css"> 
a{ text-decoration: underline; font-family: 'Myriad Pro'; } 
</style> 

<a href="#" class="typeface-js">Sign In</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Matt.
Here are the codes:

<script type="text/javascript" src="typeface-0.15.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myriad_pro_regular.typeface.js"></script>
<style type="text/css"> 
a{
text-decoration: underline; font-family: 'Myriad Pro';
}
</style>
   
<a href="#" class="typeface-js">Home</a>

Comment: and what's the css for typeface-js class...

Answer (score 0):

screenshots or a link would be useful too btw. 
maybe the underline was simulated on a parent div with border-bottom or sth?

Comment: Here are the screenshots on chrome and FF:  

http://screencast.com/t/8IWUG6LAZ  
http://screencast.com/t/myQj48V1

Comment: Where is the double underline? And please post all the relevant code.

Comment: You can notice extra thin underline on this screenshot:   http://screencast.com/t/8IWUG6LAZ     the only codes used on this typeface are the codes posted above..

Comment: Hey Jick sorry for the late answer, just took a look. Is there some sort of a iframe there? or a div with overflow:none? 

The type looks cut off from here on the left side, and notice the thin line on the left on the firefox screenshot as well, maybe there's more content in there and they're showing up a little?

Comment: Hi Ege, there's no iframe or div with overflow:none on that part. I really dont know what's going on but i just made some workaround - giving border-bottom: 1px on that element and now looks ok. Nway thanks for the response and im sorry i wasnt login back for months